# mysql if word match statement

Tags: php, mysql

how do i save the data, if
1) the word match `Pros`, it will be saved to `t_pros` column
2) the word that not match `Pros`, it will be saved to `t_others` column

i heard i can use mysql CASE statement, but dont know how to use it?

```
table pro:
id  t_pros   t_others
------------------------
1   Pros 1x
2   Pros 2x
3            voucher

<input type="text" id="t_pros">
$db->query("INSERT INTO pro(t_pros,t_others) VALUES($t_pros, $t_pros)");
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in each row only one of the two columns ever has a value?

In that case, how about:

```
$column = (preg_match('/^Pros/i', $_POST['t_pros'])) ? 't_pros' : 't_others';
$t_pros = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t_pros']);
$db->query("INSERT INTO pro($column) VALUES ($t_pros)");
```

That is, pick which column based on whether the value begins with 'Pros' or not (just as you indicated), and then just insert into that column, using MySQL's default value (normally `NULL`) for the other.

Comment: To call attention to a crucially important point @Zirak and @Thilo both mentioned explicitly, I added a call to `mysql_real_escape_string` since your code doesn't make clear if you had already done that. You MUST escape input from the user before putting it into a SQL statement.

Comment: thanks. Yea! of cuz, im aware of that :), the above code is just for the short example that i want. ;) thanks tho

Answer (score 3):

First, your input field needs the attribute name="t_pros".

Secondly, this code is open to SQL Injection - read up on it.

The query might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO pro(t_pros,t_others) VALUES(IF($t_pros = 'Pros', 'Pros', NULL), IF($t_pros = 'Pros', NULL, $t_pros))"
```

But again, this is not safe. Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) around all variables in your SQL query, or use prepared statements.

Comment: BTW, this is for when you actually have a reason to do this in SQL. The other answers using PHP for the two cases are probably a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($t_pros == 'Pros')
  $t_pros_col = $t_pros;
else
  $t_others_col = $t_pros;

$db->query("INSERT INTO pro(t_pros,t_others) VALUES($t_pros_col, $t_others_col)");
```